# ffmpeg to batch convert MXF Quicktime files to h264 while retaining 4 track audio (pass thru)

Tags: batch-file, video, ffmpeg, transcode

I have a bunch of MXF type files which have Quicktime reference files in a folder with audio components etc.

[image: video to convert]

The encoded .vid file is actually a DV codec. MPEG Streamclip will play the files but won't pass the four audio tracks through. It eaither clips 2 tracks or mixes 4 to 2.
I was hoping that there might be a way to process them from large DV25 files to smaller h264 with audio "keep as same"?

It would be great to batch them perhaps by dropping a shortcut to the Quicktime pointer file.

I can get Apple compressor to do it but I have to use a windows PC.

Comment: The reference file is a .mov and I can recall an info dump using an explicit string.  For example "ffmpeg -i camb_Prawn_730_1101(1).mov" but using a wildcard like "video.mov" would be more useful for a batch operation. Hmmm

Comment: This might be one of the (rare) cases where tag [batch-processing] might be more suitable than tag [tag:batch-file]; please read the tag infos and decide...

Comment: I will look into those thanks.